# Parsing multiple JSON types into the same struct

Tags: json, go

I am requesting an API which returns JSON containing an array of objects. The problem is that the objects can take two forms. They can either be a string or an object. An example result could look like this:

```
[
    {"name": "obj1", "key2": ["a", "b"]},
    "obj2",
    {"name": "obj3"}
]
```

A string element `"objX"` is equivalent to `{"name": "objX"}`.

I want to parse this into a slice of the following type:

```
type Obj struct {
    Name string
    Key2 []string
}
```

How do I do this in a reasonable fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Obj struct {
    Name string   `json:"name"`
    Key2 []string `json:"key2"`
}

func (o *Obj) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var name string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &name); err == nil {
        *o = Obj{}
        o.Name = name
        return nil
    }

    type Obj2 Obj
    var o2 Obj2
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &o2); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *o = Obj(o2)
    return nil
}

const payload = `[
    {"name": "obj1", "key2": ["a", "b"]},
    "obj2",
    {"name": "obj3"}
]
`

func main() {
    var objs []*Obj
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &objs); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, obj := range objs {
        fmt.Printf("Name:%v, Key2:%v\n", obj.Name, obj.Key2)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rmtSOpkYqp

Comment: Say the `Obj` struct has a lot of properties. Is there a way to avoid repeating the them this many times?

Comment: @MathiasBak Yes, using a type declaration like `type Obj2 Obj`, and assigning the result to `*o` using a type conversion: `*o = Obj(obj)`. See example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SCpSwg_vU-). I would personally recommend this instead of duplicating the struct. Or even better: declare a new type `type Obj2 Obj`, and assign the `o` itself to a value of type `*Obj2`: `var obj *Obj2 = (*Obj2)(o)`, and so you don't even to have copy the result, the `json` package will unmarsal into `o` itself. See this on the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/). This wins performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to unmarshal the varying elements of your JSON arrray into values of types you expect, and process / create an `Obj` wrapper for the `string` values should you need it.

Since your input is a JSON array, it can be unmarshalled into an array or slice. And since the elements are of different types, the element type of the Go array or slice must be `interface{}`.

Unmarshaling into a value of type `[]interface{}` would result in the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package choosing `map[string]interface{}` for the object elements. But if you populate the target slice prior with elements of the types you wish to unmarshal into, the `json` package will obediently use those:

```
func main() {
    res := []interface{}{
        &Obj{},
        "",
        &Obj{},
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &res); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range res {
        fmt.Printf("type = %-10T value = %+q\n", v, v)
    }
}

const src = `[
    {"name": "obj1", "key2": ["a", "b"]},
    "obj2",
    {"name": "obj3"}
]`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h-ced0TyB4)):

```
type = *main.Obj  value = &{"obj1" ["a" "b"]}
type = string     value = "obj2"
type = *main.Obj  value = &{"obj3" []}
```